# i keep on receiving this error on visual studio code (WildcardPatternException)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I tried to install VS Code:

1. I installed VS Code
2. Then I installed mingw64
3. Then I added the path to the environment variables
4. But I am receiving this error:

I even tried reinstalling everything twice but same output.

[image]

Comment: You're using PowerShell, not mingw64 nor Bash in that screenshot. PowerShell has its own syntax and rules.

Comment: @dai what do i do then plz?

Comment: you get a mark for the most complex directory name

Comment: first: **Don't call your program "test"**, often test is a build in command

Comment: you have `[]` in your directory name and that is interpreted by PS as wildcards

Comment: @rioV8 Wow, y'know... I never thought of that. That makes a lot of sense considering how `npm` is used implicitly in a lot of things now, and `npm test` is something that people expect to _just work_ regardless of situation.